# `Hash()` when creating a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I see many seemingly interchangeable ways to create a hash. The following all create the same hash:

```
w = {:one => 1, :two => 2}
x = Hash[:one => 1, :two => 2]
y = Hash.[](:one => 1, :two => 2)
z = Hash.send(:[], :one => 1, :two => 2)
huh = Hash(:one => 1, :two => 2)
```

As for `Hash(:one => 1, :two => 2)`, I expect to find a `:()` method for `Hash` in the documentation.  Along with the documented method `::[]`, shouldn't the documentation also list a `::()` method?

If they are both just syntactic sugar, where is the latter method documented?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `2.2.3`?

Comment: [docs.ruby-lang.org](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/) does not offer documentation specifically for 2.2.3 -- only for 2.2.0.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Either one can do, most people use [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/). The reason I asked was because you said you are using `2.3.3p173`. There is currently no such version, but there is `2.2.3p173`.

Comment: @ndn Oops - my mistake - it is `2.2.3p173`

Comment: `>> q = Hash.send(:(), :one => 1, :two => 2)
SyntaxError: unexpected '(', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
q = Hash.send(:(), :one => 1, :two => 2)
                ^` - perhaps I should have tried this...

Comment: Btw for future reference, no method in Ruby can be named `()`. It would be very strange for the interpreter and will just confuse people.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your logic here. So, basically, when you see something like `foo(bar)`, you look for an object named `foo` that has a method named `()`? Why? Usually, one would look for a method named `foo`, no?

Comment: To see where a method invoked in `self => main` comes from, you can do this: `self.class #=>Object; Object.method(:Hash).owner #=> Kernel` (or just `Object.method(:Hash) #=> #<Method: Class(Kernel)#Hash>`).

Comment: Thank you all for setting me straight on this. Very instructive!  What threw me off, I think, was that the method `:Hash` is written in uppercase.  The [convention](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars) of using lowercase `snake_case` for methods is not strictly followed, even in core Ruby?

Comment: It's convention, and it's sometimes broken when it makes sense. For example methods that return modules or classes are often named uppercase so that they rather look like parametric classes, see the [`Object#DelegateClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-DelegateClass) method in the `delegate` library in the stdlib, for example. Or the "type conversion" methods like `Kernel#Array`, `Kernel#Float`, `Kernel#Integer`, `Kernel#Rational`, `Kernel#Complex`, `Kernel#String`, `Kernel#Hash`. There's also a class named [`fatal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/fatal.html).

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag I see that `y = Hash :one => 1, :two => 2` gets the same result as well.  I take it this is "poetry mode" for `y = Hash(:one => 1, :two => 2)`, not for `y = Hash[:one => 1, :two => 2]`?

Comment: Yes, Ruby allows you to leave out the parentheses for argument lists of method calls, and it allows you to leave out the curly braces for a `Hash` literal, if it is the very last argument of an argument list. So, `foo(bar)` can also be written as `foo bar`, and `foo(bar, { :baz => 42 })` can also be written as `foo(bar, :baz => 42)`. Combining the two, we get that we can also write `foo bar, :baz => 42`. BTW: why don't you just try it yourself? `def foo(*) puts "#{__method__} called!" end; foo :one => 1, :two => 2`. Does it print "foo called" or does it `raise` a `NoMethodError` for `[]`?

Comment: @jörg-w-mittag Okay - `foo([])` gets "foo called" (was that your question?).  And I see that `foo :one => 1, :two => 2`, `foo(:one => 1, :two => 2)`, and `foo({:one => 1, :two => 2})` get "foo called". And `foo {:one => 1, :two => 2}` gets `SyntaxError`.  But I see that `foo.(:one => 1, :two => 2)` gets "foo called" _and_ `NoMethodError`. (So `foo` _does_ have a method named `()`??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a method in `Kernel` (which contains other methods that you can call directly like `Kernel.puts`) - [`Kernel.Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash). Don't use it (it's not idiomatic).

Comment: Wow. Confusing! It seems to make its appearance between [version 1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) and [2.0.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash).  I wonder why?

Comment: @user689003, [this](https://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/3131) is the thread about adding it. They just had other methods like `Kernel.Array` and thought it is only fair.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess.  But it's good to know I can ignore the Kernel method (but that it is in fact documented _somewhere_).